# Как совместить jQuery и PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html

У меня есть код на js:

```js
var text = document.getElementById("number");
var number = 1;

window.setInterval(function() {
      number = number + 1;
      text.innerText = number;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="number">1</div>
```

```
<?php $_SESSION['num'] = '?'; ?>
```

Данный код дополняет число в диве (+1).
Как значение из js встроить в переменную PHP .
Чтобы после каждой перезагрузки страницы значение продолжалось увеличиваться с того значения на которой было совершено обновление страницы.

Comment: Вся логика приложения должна размещаться на бекенде, а фронтенд только отображать. Если же вы изменяете данные на клиенте, то обновленные данные нужно отправить на бекенд и там сохранить

Answer (score 0):

Например сделать так, чтобы пхп вставлял в `$('#number')`, а jQuery брал это значение и добавлял +1 каждую секунду.

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var text = document.getElementById("number");
    var number = text.innerHTML;

    window.setInterval(function() {
        number = parseInt(number) + 1;
        text.innerHTML = number;
    }, 1000);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="number"><?php echo $_SESSION['num']?></div>
</body>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['num'] = 1;
include_once 'index.html';
?>
```

Comment: да, не. он спрашивает, как теперь после нажатия на F5 увидеть продолжение счётчика. надо где-то или передавать значение на бэк или писать в куку.